# Fetch returns 404 not found in web component

Tags: javascript, css, web-component

I have a component, `facts-and-steps.js`, and I want to import an HTML file that contains a `<template>` in it. I am trying to use `fetch` to get the `template.html` file, but it's returning a 404 error.

Here is the code that returns 404:

```
let x = await (await fetch('./template.html')).text();
//x prints "Not Found"
```

I am using the Open-wc @web/dev-server - https://modern-web.dev/docs/dev-server/overview/

How can I fetch files?

Comment: 404 mean ``./template.html`` isn't a valid reference. You can file an issue with the ModernWeb developers at: https://github.com/modernweb-dev/web/issues

Comment: Yes, I understand what 404 means. However, the HTML file is exactly in the same folder as the JS file. Isn't that supposed to work?

Comment: In vanilla Web Development, Yes; But you have to ask the Modern-Web guys, you are using their server software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` loads relative resources based on where it is executed, not where it is loaded from. Say you have `example.com/components/facts-and-steps/facts-and-steps.js` loaded and executed on `example.com/`. It will try to load `example.com/template.html`. You basically have a couple of options.

1. Load with a more complete path

```js
fetch('/components/facts-and-steps/template.html')
```

2. Use a [import.meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta). Web.dev has a [good guide](https://web.dev/bundling-non-js-resources/).

```js
fetch(new URL('./template.html', import.meta.url))
```